# Count columns where

Tags: mysql, count

My problem is in my <s>db</s> table, `amx_admins_servers` with columns `admin_id`, `server_id`, `custom_flags` and `use_static_bantime`, that looks like

[database link](http://s15.postimg.org/mz2xanr17/image.png)

and I need to count columns (server_id) that have value of 4, 7, 10, 12 and then print

```
server_id 4  - x times
server_id 7  - x times
server_id 10 - x times
server_id 12 - x times
```

The sample data only shows those 4 servers; if there were other servers, though, they should not be shown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please remember to give your tables names, and show the relevant tables in the question.  Don't make us go elsewhere for that information.  Even the linked image doesn't identify the table; it gives some column names and sample data, but that's all.  Your sample data only shows servers 4, 7, 10, 12; suppose the data included server 15 too — would you want that to show up or not?  If not, then you need to filter for the exact server IDs you're interested in.  If you'd want the information for 15 too, then life is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
select server_id, count(*) as x_times
from amx_admins_servers
where server_id in (4, 7, 10, 12)
group by server_id
```

Comment: If you can't do that by yourself then you should really take a tutorial first.